# A method written in a weird way, is my suggestion correct?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a method is someone else's program but I would rather write it in a more readable way. I just need to check whether my suggestion is correct or not.

Current Written As :

```
if (userData instanceof String && ((String) userData).compareTo(name) == 0)
```

Could be :

```
if(.... && userData.equals(name))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `compareTo` returns `0` when `equals` return `true`.

---

From the api of [`Comparable.compareTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

> **Returns:**
>
> ... a negative integer, ***zero***, or a positive integer as this object is less than, ***equal to***, or greater than the specified object. ...

From the [`String.compareTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29) api documentation:

> **Returns:**
>
> the value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string ...

Answer (score 1):

Take directly from the java doc:

> The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

Answer (score 1):

You could even simplify this further. If you're certain that `name` is a String, you could reduce it all to:

```
name.equals(userData)
```

You will have to check for nullity on `name`, though. In the original code nullity check was on account of the `instanceof` expression on `userData`.

```
name != null && name.equals(userData)
```

`String.equals()` is already checking for `instanceof String`.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
if (this == anObject) {
    return true;
}
if (anObject instanceof String) {
    String anotherString = (String)anObject;
    int n = count;
    if (n == anotherString.count) {
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;
    int i = offset;
    int j = anotherString.offset;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Good point, but if `name == null` it will throw an exception.

Comment: @dacwe Yeah. The OP isn't checking for `null`s either, though.

Comment: Well, he is, if `userData` is `null` the `instanceof String` returns `false` and if `name` is `null` its not equal to `userData`.

Comment: @dacwe Great point. Thanks for bringing this detail out. I wasn't aware that `String x = null; x instanceof String` wouldn't satisfy. I've updated the answer to note this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The instanceof then effectively only guards against null values of userData.  If you know that one or the other is non-null, you can further simplify that to:

```
if (non_null_string.equals(possibly_null_string)) {
    ....
}
```